# Why PyPlot can not work in Julia on my MAC?

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I'm using the "PyPlot" package in Julia,to plot a figure of  GaussianRandomField, Encountered some errors. I tried not plot the figrue, there is no error. So i think there might be something wrong with PyPlot.

this is my code:

```
using GaussianRandomFields, PyPlot
using Random, Printf, PyCall
pygui(true)
A = [1 0.8; 0.8 1]
an = AnisotropicExponential(A)
cov = CovarianceFunction(2,an)
pts = range(0; stop=10, length=512)
grf = GaussianRandomField(cov,KarhunenLoeve(500),pts,pts)
contourf(grf)
display(contourf(grf))
```

I got this result :

```
2019-05-20 16:20:25.337 julia[28149:332602] -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffddb7f7d90

2019-05-20 16:20:25.347 julia[28149:332602] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffddb7f7d90'

*** First throw call stack:
(
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

signal (6): Abort trap: 6
in expression starting at /Users/sat/Documents/Projects/generate_spatial_data.jl/temp.jl:9

__pthread_kill at /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib (unknown line)
Allocations: 245354859 (Pool: 245335221; Big: 19638); GC: 823
```

Can someone help to fix it out, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I can't reproduce your error under `Julia v1.1`. I got the correct plot. Wich version of Julia are you using? Can you try to update your packages, with: `using Pkg; Pkg.update()` for all of them, or individually, the ones in your code?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyPlot.jl/issues/405

it may be solved by installing a compatible matplotlib backend.